# How do I make SVN commit before each time I publish on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn

I'm running Visual Studio 2010, VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN.

Each time I use webdeploy to deploy the website, I'd like it to commit all of my files to SVN. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should investigate https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks which once installed and integrated into your project file, offer support for creating custom msbuild actions.

With it installed you can create 'SvnCommit' actions and associate it with a *beforebuild* or *afterbuild* target in your project file.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio does a build when you hit the publish button. You can create a build configuration in VS2010 that executes commands after a successful build. You should install the command line SVN client and use that to execute a commit. Call the SVN command line client from the Build Configuration.

A more common approach would be to commit your change to the version control system instead of using WebDeploy. Then have a build server get the source from version control and incorporate the changes into the server. CruiseControl.NET is a good tool for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

probably this is not the answer you are looking for - but I do not think you can get this out-of-box. I would suggest you to create a visual studio plugin and integrate it with [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) (subversion client API) to achieve what you want.

**UPDATE:**

as @maddoxej mentioned, post-build action might work as well. However, I find it's easy to miss what configuration is selected - and press F5. And committing to SVN by accident is not generally a good thing.

Another option I thought about could be VS macro. Just record a macro which clicks deploy and then commits to SVN.

Answer (score 0):

The answers that suggest making the check-in a build action is slightly flawed because the publication process will presumably increment a published build number as part of the publication process.  This will modify the source code which will then need checking-in.